# AVG scans "Installer" folder on each boot. Can I disable it?

Tags: boot, avg-antivirus

I found my PC boots pretty slow, so I used Windows Performance Toolkit to profile boot process.
What I found is "avgrsa.exe" reads every single file in "Installer" folder.

This folder is used by Windows Installer to store distributions of installed applications (.msp and .msi files).

I have 2 drives, so I moved Installer folder from small and fast SSD to big and slow HDD since I was pretty sure I will never need to access these files but only to uninstall apps.

And now each boot avg reads them. It takes ~ 15 seconds, so my PC boots about 20 seconds (versus ~ 5 seconds with out of AVG).

I can move Installer back to SSD, but it takes ~ 15GB. What I am trying to understand:

- What is the reason to read all install files?
- Can I disable it somehow?

---

I've added this folder to "Exclude", but it still accessed at boot time.
[image]

Comment: [Exclude that folder](https://support.avg.com/SupportArticleView?l=en&urlName=How-to-exclude-file-folder-or-website-from-AVG-scanning)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, but it did not help (please see my post updated)

Answer (score 1):

#### Can I disable it somehow?

Exclude the folder:

> 1. Open your AVG program.
> 2. From the Options menu select Advanced settings.
> 3. In the left pane select Exceptions.
> 4. In the right pane click Add exception.
> 5. In the drop-down menu please select the exception type.
> 6. Browse to the file, folder that you want to exclude or type URL
> 7. Click OK to save details of the exception.
> 8. Click OK again to save the settings.

Source [How to exclude files, folders or websites from AVG scanning](https://support.avg.com/SupportArticleView?l=en&urlName=How-to-exclude-file-folder-or-website-from-AVG-scanning)

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help (please see my post updated)